# Remove instance of inner element only when specific parent is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have a series of elements where I'd like it when one of the boxes is clicked the inner box on that specific element disappears. I've been playing around with it but can't get it work. I'm wondering if I should be using `this` in the code?

In the example below I want it so when you click one of the red boxes, that particular box's inner yellow box disappears, but only the yellow box inside the red box that is clicked.

I need to do it with without adding any more classes or IDs to the HTML.

CodePen: https://codepen.io/emilychews/pen/dyNPwEx

```js
var boxOuter = document.querySelectorAll(".box-outer"),
  boxInner = document.querySelectorAll(".box-inner");

if (boxOuter) {
  boxOuter.forEach(function (item) {
    item.addEventListener("click", function () {
      // code goes here
    });
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 120vh;
}

.box-outer {
  position: relative;
  width: 10rem;
  height: 5rem;
  background: red;
  margin: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box-inner {
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0.5rem;
  right: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<main class="main-wrapper">
  <div class="box-outer">
    <div class="box-inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-outer">
    <div class="box-inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-outer">
    <div class="box-inner"></div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job

```js
var boxOuter = document.querySelectorAll(".box-outer"),
  boxInner = document.querySelectorAll(".box-inner");

if (boxOuter) {
  boxOuter.forEach(function (item) {
    item.addEventListener("click", function () {
      //This will delete everything inside the box... Clear all child nodes
      this.innerHTML = '';

      //Hide inner child
      //this.children[0].style.visibility = 'hidden';
      // code goes here
    });
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 120vh;
}

.box-outer {
  position: relative;
  width: 10rem;
  height: 5rem;
  background: red;
  margin: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box-inner {
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0.5rem;
  right: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<main class="main-wrapper">
  <div class="box-outer">
    <div class="box-inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-outer">
    <div class="box-inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-outer">
    <div class="box-inner"></div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of selecting the inner element globally, you could make this inside the listener. And then use the [setAttribute method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp) to change the display property to 'none'.

```js
var boxOuter = document.querySelectorAll(".box-outer");

if (boxOuter) {
  boxOuter.forEach(function (item) {
    item.addEventListener("click", function () {
      const boxInner = item.querySelector(".box-inner"); // captures the respective box
      boxInner.setAttribute("style", "display: none;"); // sets the display attribute
    });
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 120vh;
}

.box-outer {
  position: relative;
  width: 10rem;
  height: 5rem;
  background: red;
  margin: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box-inner {
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0.5rem;
  right: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<main class="main-wrapper">
  <div class="box-outer">
    <div class="box-inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-outer">
    <div class="box-inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-outer">
    <div class="box-inner"></div>
  </div>
</main>
```